# Langchain pyPDFLoader

Tags: python, streamlit, pypdf, openai-api, langchain

I am currently trying to get started working with Langchain. I am working in Anaconda/Spyder IDE:

```
# Imports
import os 
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_chat import message



# Set API keys and the models to use
API_KEY = "MY API KEY HERE"
model_id = "gpt-3.5-turbo"

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = API_KEY

pdf_path = '.\Paris.pdf'
loaders = PyPDFLoader(".\Paris.pdf")
```

**I then run it with:**

```
streamlit run c:\users\myname\.spyder-py3\untitled0.py [ARGUMENTS]
```

I get:

The streamlit module does run and opens in the browser but I get an error.

```
ValueError: File path .\Paris.pdf is not a valid file or url
```

---

I have checked carefully and the PDF is in fact located in the correct directory (i.e. the directory where the python script is located).

As a test I also tried:

```
# Imports
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

pdf_path = './Paris.pdf'

with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
    pdf = PdfReader(file)
    num_pages = len(pdf.pages)

    for page_number in range(num_pages):
        page = pdf.pages[page_number]
        page_text = page.extract_text()
        print(f"Page {page_number + 1}:\n{page_text}")
```

This worked perfectly.
Note that I used the same path as with the langchain/streamlit version.
I have installed langchain (multiple times), pyPDF and streamlit.

I then tried:

```
import os

from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader

loader = PyPDFLoader(".\Paris.pdf")
pages = loader.load_and_split()
print(pages)
```

That works.
What is wrong in the first code snippet that causes the file path to throw an exception.

I investigated further and it turns out that the addition of the streamlit components of the code cause the file path issue to occur.

Comment: what error do you get when you just put like this `PyPDFLoader("Paris.pdf")` ?

Comment: [PrivateDocBot](https://github.com/Abhi5h3k/PrivateDocBot)

Created using langchain and chainlit 

It also streams using langchain just like ChatGpt it displays word by word and works locally on PDF data. ‍ 

code reference.

Answer (score 4):

Since it is an error of streamlit components, I would suggest you to use streamlit's `file_uploader` method as follows:

```
import streamlit as st

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload your PDF")
```

But in this case, you will have to read the pdf file in another approach which is by using `PyPDF2.PdfReader` as follows:

```
import streamlit as st
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload your PDF")
if uploaded_file is not None:
   reader = PdfReader(uploaded_file)
```

If you need the uploaded pdf to be in the format of `Document` (which is when the file is uploaded through `langchain.document_loaders.PyPDFLoader`) then you can do the following:

```
import streamlit as st
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from langchain.docstore.document import Document

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload your PDF")
if uploaded_file is not None:
    docs = []
    reader = PdfReader(uploaded_file)
    i = 1
    for page in reader.pages:
        docs.append(Document(page_content=page.extract_text(), metadata={'page':i}))
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `ValueError: File path .\Paris.pdf is not a valid file or url` is thrown from **LangChain**. See the source code >

https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/_modules/langchain/document_loaders/pdf.html

```py
[docs]    def __init__(self, file_path: str, *, headers: Optional[Dict] = None):
        """Initialize with a file path.

...

                self.file_path = str(temp_pdf)
        elif not os.path.isfile(self.file_path):
            raise ValueError("File path %s is not a valid file or url" % self.file_path)
```

Then `os.path.isfile(self.file_path)` is defined from `os.path` and `os.sep` libraries > https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sep

> The character used by the operating system to separate pathname components. This is '/' for POSIX and '\' for Windows. Note that knowing this is not sufficient to be able to parse or concatenate pathnames — use os.path.split() and os.path.join() — but it is occasionally useful. Also available via os.path.

Use `os.path.join(subdir, fname)` is recommended